# Load _id MongoDB my Object in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

JAva
I have the following problem.
I have a mobile object.

```
Calss object mobile
private ObjectId _id;
private String number;
private String nroMatricula;
```

Get and Set, etc.

When recovery of MongoDB.

```
String id = "5089e5fde4b07bf6f368366b";
DBObject soid = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(id));
String s = MongoAccess.getSingleton().GetOneValueByKey("mobile", soid);
Mobile m = js.fromJson(s, Mobile.class);

public String GetOneValueByKey(String thecollection, DBObject key)
{
    String result = null;
    try {
        DBCollection collection = MDB.getCollection(thecollection); 
     result = JSON.serialize(collection.findOne(key));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(MongoAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Recovery data correctly but the _id attribute.
I load the data I have in the database, but it generates a new id.
That should be the correct _id "5089e5fde4b07bf6f368366b" but that is not the charge on the object.
I can help.

Comment: Another solution is described at link. Both serialize and deserialize.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061611/converting-bson-type-objectid-to-json-storing-in-mongodb-java

Answer (score 3):

Solution

```
JsonDeserializer<ObjectId> des = new JsonDeserializer<ObjectId>() {

                    @Override
                    public ObjectId deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
                        return new ObjectId(je.getAsJsonObject().get("$oid").getAsString());
                    }
                };

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ObjectId.class, des).create();
```