# MongoDB "NumberLong/$numberLong" issue while converting back to Java Object

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I am having a json which is somethink like `{"Header" : {"name" : "TestData", "contactNumber" : 8019071740}}`

If i insert this to mongoDB it will be something like

`{"_id" : ObjectId("58b7e55097989619e4ddb0bb"),"Header" : {"name" : "TestData","contactNumber" : NumberLong(8019071743)}`

When i read this data back and try to convert to java object using Gson it throws exception `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a long but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 109 path $.Header.contactNumber`

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134737/read-bson-mongodb-into-pojo-using-gson-and-typeadapter), But i was wondering if i have very complex json structure then i might need to manipulate many json nodes in this approach.

Do anyone has any better alternatives on this.

**Edit:1**
I am reading querying and converting json as below

```
Document MongoDocument = mycollection.find(searchCondition);
String resultJson =  MongoDocument.toJson();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Model model= gson.fromJson(resultJson, ItemList.class);
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are reading data ?

Comment: Added the code spinet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: [converting Document objects in MongoDB 3 to POJOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209839/converting-document-objects-in-mongodb-3-to-pojos)

I had the same problem. The workaround with com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(document) does the trick.

Comment: com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(document) was deprecated in new versions

Answer (score 7):

We can use below code:

```
Document doc = documentCursor.next();
JsonWriterSettings relaxed = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.RELAXED).build();
CustomeObject obj = gson.fromJson(doc.toJson(relaxed), CustomeObject.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mongo db uses Bson format with its own types which follows json standards but it can't be parsed by json library without writing the custom wrapper/codec.

You can use third party framework/plugins to make the library take care of converting between document and pojo.

If that is not an option for you, you will have to do mapping yourself.

```
Document mongoDocument = mycollection.find(searchCondition);
Model model= new Model();
model.setProperty(mongoDocument.get("property");
```

Comment: Which third party framework/plugins you suggest for this scenario

Comment: You have many of them. I have used Morphia and Spring Mongo Db.

Comment: So in that case i see a huge drawback on using Java driver for MongoDB. I this this issue will arise in case of Date object also.

Comment: Yes you  will the same issue with date too, but this is not a drawback as this is just a driver just like your sql driver. You have to take care of mapping at Client side.

Comment: So in case of complex json where individual mapping is not possible, only way handle this is by start using framework ?

Comment: I'm not sure if framework is going to help here. I think you should revise your structure, may be denormalize it. Try to query them separately and move the complexity into business logic.

Answer (score 1):

`Document.toJson()` gives `bson` but not `json`.

I.e. for `Long` field `myLong` equals to `xxx` of `Document` it produces `json` like:

```
 "myLong" : { "$numberLong" : "xxx"}
```

Parsing of such with `Gson` will not give `myLong=xxx` evidently.

To convert `Document` to `Pojo` using `Gson` you may do next:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(document), MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: gson.toJson(document) helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
val mongoJsonWriterSettings: JsonWriterSettings = JsonWriterSettings.builder.int64Converter((value, writer) => writer.writeNumber(value.toString)).build
def bsonToJson(document: Document): String = document toJson mongoJsonWriterSettings
```